# So tell me, what am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> I can have many shapes and sizes
>
> I can have many styles and alter people's mood
>
> I am used in a famous hand game
>
> I am in many movies and usually recognized by my nickname

**What am I?**

Hint:

> Some objects can be made of me

*This is my first puzzle ever, appreciate any tips on how to improve it.*

Comment: One good idea would be to add some wordplay, because that tends to limit the possible answer space quite a lot. As the riddle now stands, it's going to be *very* broad, since there are quite many things that can be everything that is mentioned. Having a more-or-less unique solution makes a puzzle much better, and more importantly, it makes it possible to solve the riddle without guessing.

Comment: Thanks @Bass, English is not my first language so it's a little tough to add wordplay, but I will keep that in mind :). I was afraid to add too much hints and make it too easy, but I guess I added too little hints and made it too broad.

Comment: I believe the key is "I can alter people's mood" the below answers either have that and don't have the hint, or have the hint and don't have that line.

Comment: I would put the hints in the actual riddle because of Rubio's comment in his answer. Just a suggestion :)

Comment: @NL628 edited :)

Comment: That question has nothing to do with what I answered and ideally it should be removed. I question, once posted, should have some sort of persistency, otherwise it's quite pointless to answer it. It's like one of this TV shows in which they answer a silly question, then ask you something else, and stick your answer to the first question. I totally disagree with this practice and vote for this question to be removed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're a

> rock.

Namely,

> rock-paper-scissors, and Dwane "The Rock" Johnson.

Comment: You got it! You just need to edit your answer properly and explain all the phrases!

Comment: With regards to clues, the first is obvious, and third and fourth are explained here, and I'd imagine the second would be able the music genre

Comment: The second one works literally too. I mean, I know for me when I find a cool *answer-name* it makes me happy, and some *answer-name*s just look depressing. I'm starting to think I might be spending too much time around *answer-name*s...

Answer (score 8):

### Are you a

> **Lego?**

I can have many shapes and sizes

> There are many shapes and sizes of Legos

I can have many styles and alter people's mood

> There are many styles, and they can make children happy I suppose?

I am used in a famous game

> There are many games on lego.com I suppose...

I am in many movies

> The Lego Movie, the The Billion Brick Race, The Lego Movie Sequel

**Hint:**

Some objects can be made of me

> Many things can be made of Legos.

Comment: +1 But not the correct answer

Answer (score 5):

> Are you a BALL?

I can be hard

> A ball can be hard.

I can be soft

> A ball can be soft.

I can make people cry

> A lost game from any sport that uses balls can make people cry

I can make people happy

> A win can make them happy

I can be used in a game

> There are plenty of games with a ball

I can be used in a movie

> And plenty of movies about balls or games (Cast Away, Dodgeball)

Comment: Unfortunately not, a little close though, nice try! I can see my riddle becoming too broad :(

Answer (score 5):

Well, it could be

> Heart

As,

> One's heart can be hard, soft, can make one cry, happy.
> The playing cards have *hearts*.
> Many movies are based on the theme of heart, such as *Brave heart*, etc.

Comment: +1 for the nice try! Not correct though, added a hint to make it less broad.

Answer (score 5):

Are you:

> Water?

I can be hard

> Hard water

I can be soft

> Soft water

I can make people cry

> When you get water in your eyes

I can make people happy

> Ask those in the desert

I am used in a famous game

> Many famous water sports

I am used in many movies

> I guess so

Hint:  Some objects can be made of me

> Ice!

Comment: Good guess but not correct.

Answer (score 5):

> Wood

I can have many shapes and sizes

> Wood comes in many forms of trees

I can have many styles and alter people's mood

> You can make an statue out of wood. Depending on the statue someone's mood may change if it reminds them of something in the past.

I am used in a famous game

> Chessboards are commonly made out of wood

I am used in many movies

> Forests that have plenty wood, etc. Some objects can be made of me: Chessboards, doors, furniture, etc

Of course, this opens the possibility of of other materials aswell, like stone for example. But I don't know

Comment: Close but not correct :/

Answer (score 5):

<sub>This feels way too broad.

(Also, [hints are not patches on broken puzzles](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5009) - if the puzzle is too broad, *change it*, don't add hints!)</sub>

---

Another possible answer:

> **Diamond**

```
I can have many shapes and sizes
```

> Diamonds come in many sizes and cuts

```
I can have many styles and alter people's mood
```

> Again, different styles. Giving someone a diamond ring can drastically change their mood. :)

```
I am used in a famous game
```

> Among many others, Poker is a famous game. Diamonds are involved.

```
I am in many movies
```

> [Yup](http://www.imdb.com/find?q=diamond&s=tt&ref_=fn_al_tt_mr)

Hint 1 (Trying to make it less broad):

```
Some objects can be made of me
```

> Many cutting tools are made of diamond

---

Yet another possibility:

> **A ring**
>  Rings come in different sizes, [shapes and styles](https://www.jweel.com/en/blog/p/2015/the-different-ring-types/).  Rings given as gifts, or in particular engagement rings, are definitely mood altering.  Rings are used in [a famous game](https://www.walmart.com/c/ep/ring-toss-sets), and appear in a lot of movies (Hobbit / LoTR movies alone qualify as "many movies").  And chains and ring mail armor, among a lot of other things, are made of rings.

You need to further define your puzzle.  It is far too broad, and will likely be closed soon.

Comment: Really close, but not correct! Sorry about being too broad, I'm learning for the next one...

Answer (score 5):

Is the answer a:

> Jewel or a **crystal** to be more precise.

---

I can have many shapes and sizes

> Yes, [it's the case](https://www.wixonjewelers.com/education/gemstones/gemstone-guide/).

---

I can have many styles and alter people's mood

> It is said that [crystals affect moods](https://www.mindbodygreen.com/0-20957/the-only-7-crystals-you-need-to-boost-your-mood-live-your-best-life.html).

---

I am used in a famous game

> [Bejeweled](http://zone.msn.com/en/bejeweled/) probably.

---

I am in many movies

> [Yeah...](http://www.imdb.com/find?q=jewelk&s=tt&ref_=fn_al_tt_mr) and [yes](http://www.imdb.com/find?q=crystal&s=tt&ref_=fn_al_tt_mr)

---

Some objects can be made of me

> Jewellery is made out of these.

Comment: Just like @Rubio, you were close but not correct.

Comment: Check out Rubio's answer :P

Answer (score 5):

I can have many shapes and sizes

> Rocks

I can have many styles and alter people's mood

> Rock music has many different styles and alters people's moods

I am used in a famous hand game

> Rock Paper Scisors

I am in many movies and usually recognized by my nickname

> Rocks, Stone, and Rock are in many movies as is it in phrases in movies "Are you ready to rock?!"

Comment: @Billy got it first, but +1 nonetheless :)